# How to pass collection inside jeditable function?

Tags: backbone.js, jeditable

I want to edit my collection using **jeditable**, where **modifyCollection** is a function associated with the event **dblclick**. I have the following code:

```
initialize : function(options) {
        view.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.collection = this.options.collection;
        this.render();
    },

render : function() {
        var template = _.template(tpl, {
            collectionForTemplate : this.collection ,
            });
            this.el.html(template);
            return this;
    },

modifyCollection : function (event){
        $('#name').editable(function(value, settings) {
            return (value);
        }
        , 
           { onblur: function(value) {
                this.modelID=event.target.nameID;
                    this.collection = this.options.collection;

                console.log("This Collection is: " + this.collection); //Shows : undefined
                            //  
                            this.reset(value);
                    $(this).html(value); 
                    return (value); 
            }
        });
```

The idee is to update the model and subsequently, the collection by means of jeditable.  The in place editing works fine, but the problem is, I am not able to pass the collection into the function. I want to save all the changes to my collection locally and send them to the server at a later time. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, one thing I can comment on is that `this` inside your `onblur()` function is not pointing to `this` collection. Try adding `var self = this;` inside your `modifyCollection()` function then in your `onblur()` change `this.collection` to `self.collection`

Comment: @orangewarp: That comment looks suspiciously like an answer, and the right answer at that.

Comment: Yes... it does doesn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved the comment to a formal answer in case other people find this thread.

The `this` inside your `onblur()` function is not pointing to this collection. Try adding `var self = this;` inside your `modifyCollection()` function then in your `onblur()` change `this.collection` to `self.collection` like so:

```
modifyCollection : function (event) {

    var self = this;  // Added this line
    // When working with functions within functions, we need
    // to be careful of what this actually points to.

    $('#name').editable(function(value, settings) {
        return (value);
    }, {
    onblur: function(value) {
        // Since modelID and collection are part of the larger Backbone object,
        // we refer to it through the self var we initialized.
        self.modelID = event.target.nameID;
        self.collection = self.options.collection;

        // Self, declared outside of the function refers to the collection
        console.log("This Collection is: " + self.collection);
            self.reset(value);

            // NOTICE: here we use this instead of self...
            $(this).html(value); // this correctly refers to the jQuery element $('#name')
            return (value); 
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE - Foreboding Note on self**

@muistooshort makes a good mention that `self` is actually a property of window so if you don't declare the `var self = this;` in your code, you'll be referring to a window obj. Can be aggravating if you're not sure why `self` seems to exist but doesn't seem to work.

Common use of this kind of coding tends to favor using `that` or `_this` instead of `self`. You have been warned. ;-)

Comment: There's a downside to using `self` for this. The `window` object has a [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self) member so there's a global variable called `self`. The problem happens when you forget the `var self = this;`, you'll still have a `self` but it won't be the `self` you're expecting. I've switched to `var _this = this` after learning this lesson the hard way.

Comment: I think `window.self` only matters when you use frames. I've never actually had a use for it so I'm not really sure what the difference between `window` and `window.self` would be, could be a leftover from ancient times. `that` and `_this` seem to be the most common names when you don't want to use `self`. Hitting a "`self.x()` is not a function" error is maddening if you don't know that there's always a `self` in scope.

Comment: I had a panic attack until the line, if you don't declare `var self = this;`. I'm going to consider changing. I've seen people using `that` instead of `self` and it's all starting to make sense why. Question though, how is the window `self` different than using `window`? They seem to point to exactly the same thing in my console.

Comment: There are so many pitfalls it's kind of hilarious. I'm going to add this foreboding note to the answer.